# false / FALSE — any difference?

Tags: php

I noticed that some PHP frameworks use exclusively lowercase `true`/`false` and others upper.

Does it make any difference at all? I for one prefer lowercase.

Comment: Simple test `echo FALSE===false ? 'Exactly the same' : 'Values are not equal or of different types';`

Comment: @AdamBubela [Here is an ideone snippet](http://ideone.com/N12tKh).

Answer (score 72, accepted):

No difference, some people consider FALSE to be a constant and thus use the old screaming caps notation.

Comment: I've used to write `false` but lately changed to `FALSE` for better readability. Also for `TRUE` and `NULL`.

Comment: Personally prefer lower-case myself. Reads easier.

Answer (score 13):

It's been some time but because this is the first search result for the query I thought this info would be useful.

According to the [PSR-2 Coding Style Guide](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/)

> PHP keywords MUST be in lower case.   The PHP constants true, false,
>   and null MUST be in lower case.

Even though you can use the screaming caps notation; if you are trying to follow these guidelines you should be doing it in lowercase. There will be no functional difference either way.

Comment: This is a question asking if there is differences. This answer is a preference of coding styles.

Answer (score 8):

I know I'm late to the party here, but I'll just quote the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) in case anybody wants an authoritative answer, as I did.

> To specify a boolean literal, use the constants TRUE or FALSE. Both are case-insensitive.

In fact, the example immediately following the above uses this fact:

```
$foo = True; // assign the value TRUE to $foo
```

PhP is biZarRe.

Comment: The PHP FIG as well as Zend PHP Documentation state that boolean values should ideally be lower case. But from the code point of view it makes no difference.